# Create Cron Job from Thread - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking at the Whenever gem for running a process every 30 minutes that sends an email out to a specific list of customers.

The documentation gives a few examples like this one:

```
every 3.hours do # 1.minute 1.day 1.week 1.month 1.year is also supported
    runner "MyModel.some_process"
    rake "my:rake:task"
    command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

Rails runner reloads the entire app every time rails runner is executed. The same thing applies for rake and I can't think of a way to execute a command directly from the CLI without loading the entire app.

I've looked at the Clockwork gem, but the last commit there was 7 years ago. I do like the idea of having a single thread that executes functions alongside the rails application as long as the app is running.

I would think that creating a Thread and dropping it into my Model like this would work but I don't know if this is the most efficient way of accomplishing what I need.

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
    Thread.new do
        loop do
            call_some_private_function
            sleep(30 * 60)
        end
    end
end
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: you can try using sidekiq, and schedule(recurring) job with it.

Comment: Do you have any experience with AWS? AWS Lambda would be great for this

Comment: @miligraf Some, are you essentially saying to have a get request on my server and use a lambda function to make that request which runs the code?

Comment: @SachinSingh I'll look into this one more.

Comment: "Rails runner reloads the entire app every time rails runner is executed". I don't think so. It just involves a method of a Model. You even can implement in lib/test.rb and run directly from this file: rails r lib/test.rb